# How to work with Git in two computer and Heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I'm have a django app using Heroku service, and I been working on it on my linux desktop. I'm not a git expert but this is how my work flow is:

I work on my computer on certain task then I do; add, commit and then I push the project to Heroku.

Now, I just got a laptop and I want to be able to work between my laptop and desktop with the same version. Take in consideration that my django project is on a virtual environment. What is the best way to work with the way I want to work? Do I have my desktop as a Git server and client, and have my laptop as a client? How can I do this without messing around with the Heroku push. I will appreciate for any help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use one of your computer as a git server.
For safety purposes among others, you need to have your code hosted on a secured platform. Take a look at Github (most famous) or BitBucket.

Your environments should look like this:

- 2 development environments (your 2 computers). Nothing complicated here. Just learn how to use git commands to commit and retrieve your code.
- 1 git platfom (using GitHub, replaces the server you wanted to create first). It's where you push your code as soon as you want (especially when you need to save it in a secure place, or when you need to retrieve it on your other computer).
- 1 production environment (Heroku app). It's where you push your code when you want to update your live application. But it's not use to save your code (unlike Github).